# Can't access "content" key in json file from Facebook

Tags: json, python-3.x, facebook-messenger

i've downloaded my facebook data, including messages and wanted to do something with them. Let's say find the longest message in the conversation.

I've used similar code but with other keys, to access other atributes of message and it has worked, but it does not with the "content" key.

My code looks like this:

```
def extract(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        full_dict = json.load(f)
        part = full_dict["participants"]
        msg = full_dict["messages"]
    return [part, msg]


conv = extract(sys.argv[1])


def get_mess(conv):
    text= []
    for t in conv[1]:
        text.append(t["content"])
    return text
```

and this is the format of a message:

```
  {
      "sender_name": "Stasiek Janik",
      "timestamp_ms": 1555445045809,
      "content": "XD",
      "type": "Generic"
  }
```

I expected to get a list of messages' contents, just like I did with types, or timestamps. However, all I get is this error message:

```
  File "fantasy.py", line 29, in get_mess
    text.append(t["content"])
KeyError: 'content'
```

Comment: Have you seen what `conv` prints out? Make sure you are getting what you want first.

Comment: Yeah, I've checked that, it prints out what I wanted for it to print out.

Comment: Try doing this `text.append(conv[1][t]["content"])` and let me know if that works

Comment: Nope. It says "invalid syntax'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out what is wrong. It turns out that some of the messages don't have the "content" field. For example it's only notification that someone left the chat. So what I've done is I changed this part of code:

```
 def get_mess(conv):
     text= []
     for t in conv[1]:
         if "content" in t:
             text.append(t["content"])
     return text
```

Now it works just fine.